# Define a Maven plugin configuration in a parent pom and conditionate its activation in children pom

Tags: java, maven, inheritance, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I'm building a parent pom to define common version to be used for various plugin

```
<properties>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.6.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

But I also want to go further and define some profil that MAY be used by project inheriting from this pom.
For example, I want to pre-define the configuration to use MapStructs

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${mapstruct-jdk8.version}</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
        <compilerArgs>
            <compilerArg>
                -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
            </compilerArg>
            <compilerArg>
                -Amapstruct.unmappedTargetPolicy=ERROR
            </compilerArg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

How would I code this in the parent pom, so that children pom could choose to use that specific configuration or not, depending if they need to use mapstruct or not ?

Comment: You can define `profiles` in Maven with an `activation` element that references a property (defaults to `false` in the parent for instance) and let children set a different value of the activation key.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration using `<skip>` could be of use here in the child POM's:

```
 <configuration>
      <skip>true</skip>
 </configuration>
```